# $\mathbb C^2_{0} = \{(a,b)\in X: a\ne 0, b\ne 0\}$ is an open path-connected subset of $\mathbb C^2$

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, path-connected

> If $X$ is an open path-connected subset of $\mathbb C^2$, prove that $$\mathbb C^2_{0} = \{(a,b)\in X: a\ne 0, b\ne 0\}$$ is also an open path-connected subset of $\mathbb C^2$.

1. $\mathbb C^2_{0}$ is **open**.

$\mathbb C^2_{0}$ is open in the subspace topology on $X$, from which the claim follows.

2. $\mathbb C^2_{0}$ is **path-connected**.

Take $x,y\in \mathbb C^2_{0}$ (of course, $x$ and $y$ are tuples, and I am lazy). I need to find a continuous function $f: [0,1]\to \mathbb C^2_{0}$ such that $f(0) = x$ and $f(1) = y$. Since $X$ is path-connected, there exists $g: [0,1]\to  X$ with $g(0) = x$ and $g(1) = y$. My sense is that we must modify $g$ in some way (restrict to $\mathbb C^2_{0}$, or something) to construct $f$, but I am stuck here.

---

**Possible Generalization:** I wonder if the following generalization is true, for $n\in \mathbb N$:

> If $X$ is an open path-connected subset of $\mathbb C^n$, is $$\mathbb C^n_{0} = \{(a_1,a_2,\ldots,a_n)\in X: a_i \ne 0, 1\le i\le n\}$$ also an open path-connected subset of $\mathbb C^n$?

---

I was able to prove path-connectedness for a *very* special case, i.e. when $n=1$ and $X\subset \mathbb C$ is convex. I doubt if a similar idea would work for the more general cases ($X$ may not be convex, $n=2$ or greater, etc.) Take $n=1$, and let $X$ be a convex subset of $\mathbb C$. If $0\notin X$, then $C_0^1 = X$, so there is nothing to do. Assume $0\in X$. Then, $C_0^1 = X\setminus \{0\}$. Consider $x,y\in C_0^1$, and the straight line path in $X$ given by $f:[0,1]\to X$ such that $f(t) = (1-t)x + ty$ for $t\in [0,1]$. If $f(t)\ne 0$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, then $f:[0,1]\to C_0^1$ is the required path in $C_0^1$. If $f(t) = 0$ for some $t\in [0,1]$ (there is at most one such $t$), then consider $z\notin f([0,1])$. Define $g_1:[0,1]\to C_0^1$ by $g_1(t) = (1-t)x + tz$ and $g_2:[0,1]\to C_0^1$ as $g_2(t) = (1-t)z + ty$. Concatenate $g_1$ and $g_2$ to get $g:[0,1]\to C_0^1$.
$$g(t) = \begin{cases}g_1(2t) & t\in [0,1/2]\\ g_2(2t-1) & t\in [1/2,1] \end{cases}$$
$g$ is the required path between $x$ and $y$ in $C_0^1$.

Thanks!

Comment: *Hint*: Can you do the case of $\mathbb{C}^1$?

Comment: Thanks, I withdraw my comment. ;P

Comment: @user10354138 I could do a special case of $n=1$, I have added it an edit.

Comment: Here is another way of thinking about the first problem (showing openness). Recall that the intersection of two open sets is open. Given that $X$ is open, can you find another open set $U \in \mathbb C^2$ such that $\mathbb C^2_0 = X \cap U$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\Cpx}{\mathbf{C}}$Here are some suggestions.

1. fish has hinted at the "right" proof of openness.
2. For path connectedness, the intuition is we're removing two complex lines from $\Cpx^{2}$. Since these have real codimension $2$, they don't separate $X$. To prove this, we might

- Show that every continuous path $f$ in the connected open set $X$ can be homotoped to a polygonal path in $X$.
  Hint:

> One way to do this rigorously is to cover the image of $f$ with open polydisks $D$ contained in $X$. Use compactness to select a finite subcovering $(D_{k})_{k=0}^{n}$ in such a way that $f(0) \in D_{0}$, $f(1) \in D_{n}$, and $D_{k-1} \cap D_{k}$ is non-empty for $1 \leq k \leq n$; that is, construct a "chain of polydisks" in $\Cpx_{0}^{2}$ covering the image of $f$. Let $x_{0} = f(0)$, $x_{n+1} = f(1)$, and for each $k$ with $1 \leq k \leq n$, pick a point $x_{k}$ in $D_{k-1}\cap D_{k}$ and on the image of $f$, say $x_{k} = f(t_{k})$ for some $t_{k}$ in $[0, 1]$. Note that both $x_{k}$ and $x_{k+1}$ are in $D_{k}$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$. Do a straight-line homotopy between $f$ on $[t_{k}, t_{k+1}]$ and the constant-velocity segment $\overline{x_{k}x_{k+1}}$; this homotopy stays within $D_{k}$, and hence within $\Cpx_{0}^{2}$, because polydisks are convex.

- If the resulting polygonal path, a finite union of segments, avoids the union of the coordinate axes, we're done. Otherwise, use your argument about convex subsets of $\Cpx$ to deform a segment away from the union of the coordinate axes, obtaining a path in $\Cpx_{0}^{2}$. This can be done one coordinate at a time. Alternatively, argue directly that a Cartesian product of path-connected spaces is path-connected, so the product of a disk and a punctured disk, or of two punctured disks, is path-connected. It follows that $D_{k} \cap \Cpx_{0}^{2}$ is path-connected, so we can join $x_{k}$ to $x_{k+1}$ in $D_{k} \cap \Cpx_{0}^{2}$ for each $k$ with $0 \leq k \leq n$. Either way, we get a continuous path between $f(0) = x_{0}$ and $f(1) = x_{n+1}$ in $\Cpx_{0}^{2}$.

Comment: Could you add more details for *"Otherwise, use your argument about convex subsets of $\mathbf C$ to deform a segment away from the union of the coordinate axes, obtaining a path in $\mathbf C_{0}^{2}$. This can be done one coordinate at a time."* I also do not understand the part that follows, i.e. the alternative argument.

Comment: 1. Briefly, a path here is an ordered pair $(z_1,z_2)$ of functions. If (say) $z_1(t_0)=0$ for some $t_0$, your argument shows how to modify $z_1$ to avoid $0$. The point is we can modify each component separately to avoid either coordinate being $0$. <> 2. In the second step, we've constructed a chain $(D_k)_{k=0}^n$ of polydisks and/or punctured polydisks, and a sequence of points $(x_k)_{k=0}^{n+1}$ with $f(0)=x_0$, $f(1)=x_{n+1}$, and $x_k$, $x_{k+1}$ in $D_k$ for each $k$. If we show each $D_k$ is path-connected, we can join $f(0)$ to $f(1)$ by a path.

Comment: How do you conclude that $D_k \cap \mathbf C_0^2$ is one of the three forms you mentioned (product of discs, punctured discs, or one of each)? Also, do you have any thoughts about the more general question for $\mathbf C_0^n$? I could create a separate post for it, if that is too detached from the $n=2$ case.

Comment: I'd think of it as: $\mathbf{C}_0^2$ is $X$ with the "axes" $ab=0$ removed. Since $D_{k}$ is a polydisk with the axes removed, it has one of the stated forms depending whether it crosses either axis (though the point removed need not be the center, so really we're talking "up to biholomorphism"). <> An argument for the $n$-dimensional case should work along similar lines: The sets removed are complex hyperplanes, so of real codimension $2$.

Answer (score 1):

Notation: For $(x,y)\in\Bbb C^2$ let $\|(x,y)\|=\sqrt {|x|^2+|y|^2}.$

Let $Y=X\setminus \{(0,0)\}.$ If $(0,0)\not\in X$ then $Y=X$ & the Q is trivial. So assume $(0,0)\in X.$

Take any $b,c\in Y.$ Let $f:[0,1]\to X$ be continuous with $f(0)=b$ and $f(1)=c.$

If $(0,0)\not\in\{f(t): t\in [0,1]\}$ then $f$ is a path in $Y$ from $b$ to $c$ and we are done.

Suppose instead that $0<t_0<1$ and $f(t_0)=(0,0).$ Take $r>0$ such that $2r<\min (\|b\|,\|c\|)$ and such that $\{d\in  \Bbb C^2: \|d\|<2r\}\subset X.$ This is possible because $X$ is open and $(0,0)\in X$.

Let $E=\{e\in \Bbb C^2: \|e\|=r\}.$ Then $E\subset Y.$

$(\bullet ). $ Show that $E$ is a path-connected space.

Now let $t_1=\inf \{t\in  [0,t_0]:\|f(t)\|\le r \}$ and let $t_2=\sup \{t\in  [t_0,1]:\|f(t)\|\le r \}.$ Then $0<t_1\le t_2<1.$ And $f(t_1),f(t_2)\in E.$ And $t\in [0,1]\setminus (t_1,t_2)\implies \|f(t)\|\ge r\implies f(t)\ne (0,0).$

Now   $f|_{[0,t_1]}$ is a path in $Y$ from $b$ to $f(t_1)$...

and there is a path in $E\subset Y$ from $f(t_1)$ to $f(t_2)$...

and $f|_{[t_2,1]}$ is a path in $Y$ from $f(t_2)$ to $c.$